# How to invoke CommandLineRunner after input data in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot app in which I created a POST method, that expects some input from the user via HTML Thymeleaf. Once the input gets fetched, I am producing a string that represents a final URL. Then I want to pass this string URL in my Configuration Class that contains a CommandLineRunner.

The problem is that `CommandLineRunner` gets executed upon the application start which means that my input has null values thus throwing Null Pointer Exception. Is it possible to add data for my `CommandLineRunner` after application's start-up and somehow the execution of the latter goes smoothy???

**REST CONTROLLER CLASS**

```
package com.andrekreou.covid.gov.controller;

import com.andrekreou.covid.gov.model.Covid;
import com.andrekreou.covid.gov.model.Date;
import com.andrekreou.covid.gov.service.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    private final Service service;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/covid")
    public List<List<Covid>> getData(){
        return service.getData();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/insert/date")
    public String insertDate(@ModelAttribute("date") Date date) {
        String inserted_date = date.getDate();
        return "https://data.gov.gr/api/v1/query/mdg_emvolio?date_from=" + inserted_date + "&date_to=" + inserted_date;
    }
}
```

**CONFIG CLASS**

```
package com.andrekreou.covid.gov.configuration;

import com.andrekreou.covid.gov.controller.Controller;
import com.andrekreou.covid.gov.model.Covid;
import com.andrekreou.covid.gov.model.Date;
import com.andrekreou.covid.gov.repository.CovidRepo;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class CovidConfig {

    Controller controller;

    Date date;

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(CovidRepo covidRepo){
        return args -> {

            String url = controller.insertDate(date);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.set("Authorization","Token 8329eb4fa30e567d9e3f6bfed266c8cb4c9c94ad");

            HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

            ResponseEntity<List<Covid>> postEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                    url,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    request,
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
                    });

            List<Covid> covidList = postEntity.getBody();
            assert covidList != null;
            covidRepo.saveAll(covidList);
            System.out.println(covidList);
        };
    }
}
```

**POJO CLASS**

```
package com.andrekreou.covid.gov.model;

public class Date {

    private String date;

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

**HTML THYMELEAF**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>login</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #3e3e3e;
            color: white;
        }
        h2 {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <form class="date" name="date" method="post" action="/insert/date" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <h2 class="form-register-heading">Please Enter Date</h2>
        <p>
            <label for="date" class="sr-only">Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="date" placeholder="date" required=""
                   autofocus="">
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Insert Date</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can add @Order to the Covid Config class but it's not quite the answer to your question. You can solve business logic in the CommandLineRunner class using Rest or Message Broker(Kafka,RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, JMS, Socket Programing(TCP-UDP),gRPC) any of these. The simplest approach would be the Rest architecture.



As a solution, if you don't have access to the code you want to get the data from, you can write a code that will run every 1 hour and not save the same data. If you have access to the code, the above items will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little bit strange. As you say that this functional interface is called when we run our applications with command-line(So it is called `CommandLineRunner`) and at that time we may give some params from command prompt like that `java -jar MyApp "param1" "param2"`. param1 and param2 are passed to main method as params. So it is called only one time.

> CommandLineRunner is a simple Spring Boot interface with a run method.
> Spring Boot will automatically call the run method of all beans
> implementing this interface after the application context has been
> [loaded](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app).

PS: if you want to call your business logic after the completion of the method, You can you Spring AOP. if you have another scenario like performing a method in a different thread,  may use ExecutorServices class in order to reach it or you can implement it by yourself.

Comment: The purpose of my question has to do with the fact that `CommandLineRunner` starts together with my `@SpringBootApplication` main method. But I want to know if it is somehow possible to be able to add some input data on `CommandLineRunner` after application's start-up.

Comment: Yes but you should change application args, But I think it is not a best practice, It may affect your application negatively. You can do with this way https://gist.github.com/samandarjon/674e4a37a3f9499a375dd0635af01e9a

Comment: During the program running, you are not able to change the args,  However, again you can call run method of CommandLineRunner interface with other params